# Making pairs of two integers, every other integer from a file

Tags: java, int

I have a code that populates two int[] arrays with numbers from 0-255.
I need to make it possible to read a file, and group every other integer together, for example my file is 0 12 85 45 20 14 255 145, I need to make pairs that will be 0-12, 85-45, 20-14, 255-145.
Do you have any suggestions?

```
try {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("input.txt")));
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("output.txt")));
    int[] i = new int[256];
    int[] j = new int[256];
    for (int k = 0; k < 256; k++) {
        i[k] = k;
        for (int l = 0; l < 256; l++) {
            j[l] = l;
            System.out.println(k + " " + l);
        }
    }
    //the int pairing should be here
    //but I have no idea how to pair the integers from the input.txt file
}
```

Comment: Lose the loop entirely, you're not iterating every number from `0-255`, you're iterating the numbers in a file. I would also reconsider `DataInputStream` if you can, as `#readInt` on that class doesn't support whitespaces (but using `Scanner` and `Scanner#readInt`, you can get the next number regardless of whitespace). Otherwise, there's always `#readLine` and `String#split`, these should help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream api suggests quite concise solution:

```
String string = Files.readString(Paths.get(PATH_TO_FILE));  // get file content
String[] arr = string.split(" ");

List<String> pairs = IntStream.iterate(0, n -> n < arr.length, n -> n + 2)
        .mapToObj(i -> arr[i] + "-" + arr[i + 1])
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(pairs);    // [0-12, 85-45, 20-14, 255-145]
```